# Override Customer Account Edit on Frontend

Tags: magento2.3, overrides, customer-account, edit

Magento 2 newbie.  I am trying to override the default 'Customer Account Edit' form on the Frontend. I'm not able to get my template to "override", its always loading the default template [`/html/public/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml`].  The issue may be with my layout but I'm not certain of the syntax. Using 'Vendor/Module' as an example.

My Layout File:

> /html/public/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer_account">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Vendor_Module::customer/form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Does anyone know if I'm using the correct reference container or if that's even the issue I'm facing?

Comment: The only way I have been able to get Magneto to load my template is to either remove the core layout file [/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml] so that it loads my layout file [/app/code/MyVendor/MyComponent/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml] or change the template directly in the core layout file.    Basically I am unable to get my layout file to load.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Xigen_CC::form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="email_cc" template="Xigen_CC::form/email_cc.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC/blob/eb29ce70042d2fdc755a855c7e7b181a671a3367/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml#L80

```
 <?=$block->getChildHtml('email_cc')?>
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/form/email_cc.phtml

```
<?php
$emailCc = $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('email_cc');
$customerEmailCC = $emailCc ? $emailCc->getValue() : null;
?>
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" >
    <legend class="legend">
        <span><?=$block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email Copy To'))?></span>
    </legend>
    <br>
    <div class="field email_cc">
        <label for="email_cc" class="label"><span><?=$block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email Address (Comma separated)'));?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input id="email_cc" class="input-text" name="email_cc" value="<?=$block->escapeHtmlAttr($customerEmailCC);?>" title="<?=$block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email Copy To'));?>" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The only way I have been able to get Magneto to load my template is to either remove the core layout file [/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml] so that it loads my layout file [/app/code/MyVendor/MyComponent/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml] or change the template directly in the core layout file.  B